# Mysql query results 1 record total but 0 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to validate a user login at database.
Running this SELECT query at phpMyadmin, the result is "Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0011 sec)".
For this reason the mysqli_num_rows($query) count is null when I echoes it.
What is wrong?

```
        $sql = "SELECT 
            Id_Usuario,
            Nome_Usuario,
            Matricula_Usuario,
            Email_Usuario,
            Senha_Usuario,
            Perfil_Usuario,
            Status_Usuario
            FROM USUARIO
            WHERE Email_Usuario = '".$email."' AND Senha_Usuario = '".$senha."' 
            LIMIT 1";

    $query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) or die('Problem running query: ' . mysql_error());
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $Id_Usuario = $row['Id_Usuario'];
        $Nome_Usuario = $row['Nome_Usuario'];
        $Matricula_Usuario = $row['Matricula_Usuario'];
        $Email_Usuario = $row['Email_Usuario'];
        $Senha_Usuario = $row['Senha_Usuario'];
        $Perfil_Usuario = $row['Perfil_Usuario'];
        $Status_Usuario = $row['Status_Usuario'];
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an entry with the given e-mail and password (senha)? Also, I can see your code is written in portuguese, if you wish to you may use the [portuguese version of StackOverflow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: First try to print the $sql value. then check wheather you are getting the value of $email, $senha. then run this code in phpmyadmin . I think there something is missing

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, the result "Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0011 sec)" is given by the phpMyAdmin.